# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on portable hard drive and still use it for storing files?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I have seen that you can install Ubuntu on a portable hard drive, but I am asking myself this question: will I be able to keep using the hard drive for personal data storage even after the install. If I'm not mistaken, Windows won't allow to split partitions in a hard drive (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Thanks for your time and your answers!

(Sorry I'm new to all this, trying to adapt!)

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because i don't know if it works, and i don't know anything about the software mentioned, but here are two links that suggest it's possible: http://achugh.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/multi-partition-a-usb-flash-drive-in-windows/ http://www.ehow.com/how_5856009_create-multiple-partitions-usb-drive.html

Answer (score 0):

well, ubuntu uses different file systems than windows does.

your external hdd is probably in ext4 file system format now, rather than ntfs or fat which windows likes to read. so your short answer would be no, it will not work like that...

But, you may consider using this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

it will allow you to read the external hdd and pull files from it, but i cannot remember if it will allow you to write to it... why not try the program and play with it a bit? :)